# How do I repeat block of code to document end?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code which does work but only once, I'd like to cycle it through to the end of the document.

```
Sub AddBrackets()
    Dim iCount As Integer
    iCount = 1
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Size = 6

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "^&"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute
    While Right(Selection.Text, 1) = " " Or _
            Right(Selection.Text, 1) = Chr(13)

        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=1, _
            Extend:=wdExtend
        iCount = iCount + 1
    Wend

    Selection.InsertAfter "]"
    Selection.InsertBefore "["
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=iCount
    Beep
End Sub
```

Trying to implement the process as shown by Freeflow, and in response to his comments.
These are the ones I have tried...

```
Do While .Find.Execute
    .Select
    '.MoveStartUntil CSet:="0123456789", count:=wdBackward
    '.MoveStartUntil CSet:="0123456789", count:=wdForward
    '.MoveStart wdCharacter, -1
    .MoveStartWhile cset:="123456789", count:=-1
    '.MoveStartWhile cset:=Chr$(13) Or " ", count:=wdBackward
    '.MoveEndWhile CSet:=Chr$(13), count:=wdBackward
    .InsertAfter "]"
    .InsertBefore "["
    .MoveStart unit:=wdCharacter, count:=.Characters.count
    .Select
Loop
```

Changes made to the code. None of these changes seem to work

Comment: use `For i=1 to 100 Next` Loop Statment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You request is a common operation in Word.  Find something and then carry out an operation that is not part of the Find/Replace function.

The following code does what you ask. You will note that everything can be done within word.  The Word object model is quite powerful and flexible and pays some time taken to get familiar with what is available.  Unfortunately , you won't get this if you just read recorded macros, you have to dig into the object model and use F1 a lot.

If you need the code to start from a selection and then work through the remainder of the document you will have to modify the code below.

The do loop takes advantage of the fact that at that stage the current range is the text found by the .execute.

```
Public Sub search()

Const REPLACEMENT_TEXT                      As String = "^&"
Const FIND_TEXT                             As String = vbNullString

    With ActiveDocument.Content

        With .Find

            .ClearFormatting
            .Font.Size = 6
            .text = FIND_TEXT
            .Replacement.text = REPLACEMENT_TEXT
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = True

        End With

        Do While .Find.Execute

            '.Select
            .MoveStartWhile cset:=Chr$(13) & " ", Count:=wdBackward
            .InsertAfter "]"
            .InsertBefore "["
            .MoveStart unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=.Characters.Count
            '.Select

        Loop

    End With

    Beep

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great "but" if the character following the selection is a carriage return it moves one character past the carriage return and inserts the ] after the Carriage return, in most instances the selection is at the end of the line, but not always. I'm at a loss...

Comment: @JovialJohn Insert a '.MoveEndWhile cset:=Chr$(13), count:=wdbackward before the first insert

Comment: Back at this, I can't get it to select only the character, it also selects the space or carriage return after the character. Can I get it to select only the character, either a 1 2 or 3 digit number.

Comment: Yes that's possible.  The answer you need is in  the MoveStartWhile. I'm assuming that you have used F1 on MoveStartWhile and understand that you can reverse the logic using MoveStartUntil.